# Handling drag and drop: view or business logic?

Tags: java, swing, model, view

I have a TransferHandler class that is used to handle file drag and drop. It is applied to Swing components and as such interacts with the view.

My question is as follows:

- In an MVC, where would this class be found in the controller part?
- In a mix of a layered architecture (data, biz, presentation) and MVC would this class be in the business logic or would there be a subpackage containing logic specific to the view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you change your interface to CLI(console), will TransferHandler be placed in your controller part? - No. So, it is view.

Comment: Thanks. I just needed the reasoning to formulate a question for quick thinking. So in a layered architecture there'd also be a package with some view specific logic and means it is considered as a form of input validation/checking.

Answer (score 3):

Couple of nice articles about the subject:

http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html

http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/SeparatedPresentation.html

Comment: I agree and they're from Fowler himself :)